# Has the pronunciation of ‘heretic’ changed over time?

Tags: pronunciation

One says ‘HERetic’ and ‘heRETical’ and I was wondering if ‘heRETic’ is or has ever been correct, or v.v. ‘HERetical’ (doesn’t feel ok’)

Comment: There are exceptions, and there is some flexibility, but the stress in English is typically placed on the antepenultimate syllable - the third syllable from the end.

Comment: This is especially true of words borrowed from Latin, which had a similar rule.

Answer (score 1):

Note that accented syllables can vary greatly especially between US and UK versions.

---

I'm British and I have only ever heard ‘HERetic’ for the noun.

If I heard ‘heRETic’ I would assume it was intended as an adjective not a noun - an abbreviation of ‘heRETical’

**Examples**

Pelagius was a British HERetic. (noun)

Pelagius was a heRETical Briton. (adjective)

Pelagius was a heRETic Briton. (not standard usage but I would assume it was a form of "heretical")

Comment: Thank you. I must have been influenced by the hisTORIc, etc., adjective pronunciation pattern in this feeling. I do now wonder if heretic may have been an adjective before  it became a noun. Ahh, the beauty of language. Which reminds me of Calvin (from Calvin and Hobbes) saying: “verbing nouns weirds language”.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if ‘heRETic’ is or has ever been correct, or v.v. ‘HERetical'

No.

Lawrence is right in thinking that *[the stress in English is typically placed on the antepenultimate syllable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/543462/has-the-pronunciation-of-heretic-changed-over-time#comment1334555_543462)*.

Although *heretic* ends with *-ic*, it's a noun. I think the *-ic* in 'heretic' is not a suffix.

Words that end with the suffix *-ic* are usually stressed on the penultimate syllable (second last syllable).

Examples: Historic, ecstatic, empathetic etc.

Most nouns are usually stressed on the first syllable. So 'heretic' is stressed on the first syllable and is pronounced /'herətɪk/.

On the other hand, *heretical* is an adjective and adjectives that end with *-ical* are usually stressed on the antepenultimate syllable (third-last syllable), so 'heretical' is stressed on the antepenult: /hə'retɪk(ə)l/.

Other words that end with *-ical* and are stressed on the antepenult are *historical, empirical, cynical* etc.